# DC Comics Multiverse structure

Tags: dc, comics

I'm sometimes read DC comics. I read this without thinking much about the structure of this. DC Multiverse turned out to be more complicated for me than I thought. So I have a few questions about this:

**1. What was the structure of the multiversum before, during and after The Crisis and in particular eras (Golden Era, Silver Era, Bronze Era)?** How much worlds multiverse had in pre-Crisis, during Crisis and post-Crysis?

**2. Is there a list of all DC Realities(comics, tv serials, films, defunct, existing, destroyed, crossovers in one word all that was created by DC)?**

**3. Suppose that I'm starting reading DC comics from the start (from first pre-Crysis comics). What order should I follow of course if it is an order in this?**

**4. What is flashpoint?**

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Multiverse - Multiverse, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Multiverse_worlds - List of Universes, http://www.alltimelines.com/dc-comics-multiverse-chronology/ - Timeline in order starting from Pre-Crisis, http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Flash:_Flashpoint - Flashpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of your answers can be found [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Multiverse) (many of its facts coming from *[The Multiversity Guidebook](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/The_Multiversity_Guidebook_Vol_1_1)*).

1. The initial multiverse was an infinite number of overlapping universes created as a result of Krona's interference in the Big Bang, and destroyed during the Crisis on Infinite Earths, whereupon there was only one New Earth, albeit in an unstable state.
2. The Zero Hour multiverse was a series of separate Hypertime timelines that were later rolled into the general multiverse concept.
3. The Interregnum Multiverse was part of the Infinite Crisis storyline and was was created by Alexander Luthor. It collapsed, but its various aspects informed New Earth history.
4. The [Flashpoint](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Flash:_Flashpoint) universe was the result of Barry Allen changing the events of the universe. It was not strictly a multiverse, being an altering of the prime New Earth timeline, but it did merge three different universes into one (with the help of Dr. Manhattan), resulting in the New 52 multiverse.
5. The New 52 multiverse was intended to be the simplified canon, where there are 52 specific universes that exist, no more and no less.
6. However, the events of *Convergence*, and the mandate of John King, has stated that "Post-Convergence, every character that ever existed, in either Continuity or Canon, is now available to us as storytellers," which may mean that any or all of the prior Multiverses now also exist.

Here is a partial list of named universes:

> - *Antimatter Universe*: The home universe of Oa's antimatter counterpart, Qward.
> - *Crossover Earth*: A world where the Marvel and DC characters coexist.
> - *Earth-One*: The Modern Age of heroes including Martian Manhunter and the JLA.
> - *Earth-Two*: The First Age of heroes including an elder Superman and Batman and the JSA.
> - *Earth-Two-A (Alternate Earth-Two)*: An Earth suggested by E. Nelson Bridwell in Superman Family to address the 1940s and 1950s Superman stories that had Silver Age characteristics.
> - *Earth-Three*: Evil counterparts of Earth-One's heroes
> - *Earth-Four*: The homeworld of Blue Beetle, Captain Atom, Nightshade, The Question, Peacemaker, Thunderbolt, Judomaster, and Sarge Steel.
> - *Earth-Five*: A world with no Krypton or superheroes, the Phantom Stranger brings Earth-One's Batman to this universe to prevent the deaths of his parents and inspires this world's Bruce Wayne to grow up to become Batman.
> - *Earth-Six*: The United States lost the Revolutionary War. Lady Quark and Lord Volt rule America as superpowered monarchs.
> - *Earth-Seven*: Homeworld of Dark Angel.
> - *Earth-Twelve*: Homeworld of the Inferior Five (part of "Earth-B")
> - *Earth-Fourteen*: Jack Kirby's Fourth World.
> - *Earth-86*: Homeworld of the Atomic Knights defending a war-ravaged nuclear landscape.
> - *Earth-96*: Kingdom Come.
> - *Earth-97*: Tangent Comics.
> - *Earth-162*: World where Superman was split into Superman Red and Superman Blue, each 100 times smarter than the original, who solved all their Earth's problems and created a New Krypton.
> - *Earth-276*: The Home Universe of Captain Thunder. Earth-Forty is a close variant where Captain Thunder's real id is Billy Batson rather then William Fawcett.
> - *Earth-901*: Home to the Just Imagine Stan Lee Created the DC Universe characters.
> - *Earth-1191*: Tales of the Multiverse: Batman-Vampire.
> - *Amalgam Universe*: World created by the merging of the Marvel Universe and the DC Universe.
> - *Earth-A*: The evil Johnny Thunder of Earth-One altered the history of the Justice League to create the Lawless League.
> - *Earth-AD:* (presented as two similar realities, Earth-86 and Earth-295 in the Crisis on Infinite Earths: The Compendium): A wrecked future world where humanlike animals rule the Earth, and Kamandi is the last boy.
> - *Earth-B*: An explanation for inconstancies in Brave and the Bold and World Finest Comics and the main Earth-One reality. Formally revealed in Crisis on Infinite Earths: The Compendium as two Earths: Earth-Twelve and Earth-Thirty-Two. The Compendium confirmed that the events of DC Challenge took place on the Earth-Thirty-Two part of "Earth-B".
> - *Earth-C*: Home to anthropomorphic animals including Captain Carrot and His Amazing Zoo Crew.
> - *Earth-D*: Consisted of the Justice Alliance of America and other analogues of heroes from Earth-One, but were more ethnically diverse.
> - *Earth-Prime*: Homeworld of Ultraa and Superboy-Prime.
> - *Earth-S*: The Marvel Family's Earth.
> - *Earth-X (Two)*: The adopted home of Earth-Two natives, the Freedom Fighters. Roosevelt's death in 1944 resulted in a delay in the Manhattan Project allowing the Nazis to also develop the bomb. The resulting conventual war ends with a Nazi victory due to them inventing a mind control device in 1968.
> - *Limbo*: A dimension inhabited by long forgotten DC characters.

As for reading order, I really feel that it does not matter because the status quo keeps changing.

Comment: Hey, you left out Earth-C-Minus, home of the Just'a Lotta Animals (from *Captain Carrot and His Amazing Zoo Crew* 14-15). And others, I'm sure - but how can you mention Earth-C and leave out Earth-C-Minus? :-)